# Reading from file, but I'm not able to print the last line?

Tags: c, file-handling

I'm attempting to read in from a file using fscanf (teacher's pretty much requiring this, I personally would use getline or something else) and I'm attempting to read until the end of the file - my code seems to work fine, except that it doesn't seem to print out the last line of the file I'm reading when I return to the outer loop and I'm not sure why (it does print it when I call the readLine function and print out the lines that I get inside *that* function however)

If someone could look over my code and let me know where I'm going wrong, I'd really appreciate it. (Please ignore the rather weird looking if-statements in main, that's for future code that I haven't gotten to yet.)

**most_freq.h**

```
#ifndef MOST_FREQ_H_
#define MOST_FREQ_H_

#include <stdio.h>

//used to hold each "word" in the list
typedef struct word_node
{
char *word;
unsigned int freq; //frequency of word 
struct word_node *next;
} word_node;

struct node *readStringList(FILE *infile);

int readLine(FILE *infile, char * line_buffer);

struct node *getMostFrequent(struct word_node *head, unsigned int num_to_select);

void printStringList(struct word_node *head);

void freeStringList(struct word_node *head);

int InsertAtEnd(char * word, word_node *head);

char *strip_copy(const char *s); //removes any new line characters from strings

#endif
```

**most_freq.c**

```
#include "most_freq.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct word_node *head = NULL; //unchanging head node
char* str_buffer = NULL;

struct node *readStringList(FILE *infile) {
    char* temp_buffer = malloc (sizeof(char) * 255); //buffer for 255 chars
    while(readLine(infile, temp_buffer) == EXIT_SUCCESS && !feof(infile)) { //while there is still something to be read from the file
        printf("Retrieved Line: %s\n", str_buffer);
    }
}
int readLine(FILE *infile, char * line_buffer) {
   fscanf(infile, "%s", line_buffer);
   str_buffer = strdup(line_buffer);
   if(str_buffer[0] != '\0' || strcmp(str_buffer, "") != 0) {
    return EXIT_SUCCESS; //return success code
   }
   else {
    return EXIT_FAILURE; //return failure code
   }
}

int InsertAtEnd(char * word, word_node *head){
}

void printStringList(struct word_node *top) {
}

char *strip_copy(const char *s) {
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2) // no arguments were passed
    {
        FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r"); /* "r" = open for reading, the first command is stored in argv[1] */
        if ( file == 0 )
        {
            printf( "Could not open file.\n" );
        }
        else
        {
            readStringList(file);
        }
    }
    else if (argc < 3) {
        printf("You didn't pass the proper arguments! The necessary arguments are: <number of most frequent words to print> <file to read>\n");
    }
}
```

text file

```
foofoo
dog
cat
dog
moom
csci401isfun
moon$
foofoo
moom.
dog
moom
doggod
dog3
f34rm3
foofoo
cat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the last line is read, the File *is* at the end. Your function still returns EXIT_SUCCESS (and the last line), but you additionally check for EOF: `... && !feof(infile)`, so processing ends before the last line is printed.

Comment: that...makes sense, I swapped the two conditions and it works perfectly now! thanks!